# How to put Sabre booking in queue (booking now and create PNR later before specific time)?

Tags: sabre

working on sabre AIR API.
Working on booking workflow, including the API's as:

> 1. EnhancedAirBookRQ
> 2. PassengerDetailsRQ

and

> EnhancedAirTicketRQ

for ticketing(creating PNR of the booking)

Anyone can tell for any API available in sabre, using I can put tickets in queue, that booking now but creating PNR for it at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use QueuePlaceLLSRQ to place the PNRs you plan to ticket later. You can create any queue using numbers other than the ones used by system queues (0-49). Then you could access the queue and use EnhancedAirTicketRQ.

Comment: It is recommended to use Ticketingtimelimit for this and not use queplace

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the Tickettingtimelimit (TAW for GUI users) in the Passengerdetails request. The PNR will then land on your Queue 9 in the specified time

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not so clear, because just to let you
>   know. there are two important points in a reservation, 1st Creating
>   PNR, 2nd Issue this PNR to issue a PNR your are going to need a PQ

Step by Step to create a PNR and Issue a ticket

Just to clarify you can have a PNR without a ticket and to have a PNR is not required issuing it.

Note you can start by first adding the Pax information or add Origin and destination information, feel free.

1. Search for segment flight
2. Display fare rule
3. Price Itinerary
4. Add passenger information into the PNR
5. Store fare and ticketing instructions in a Price Quote (PQ) Record

    - ***Very important point: without a PQ you can't issue and you can't guarantee the price***
6. Add ticketing field

   - ***Here is the point that you are looking for. at this step you are gonna to add the last date to purchase (date to be ticketed)***
   - Add ticketing for future date.

     - Places PNR on queue using the service (QueuePlaceRQ) on specified date

       - ***Remember you must have to setup and configure Sabre's Queues before to use it you can have lots of Queues configured, so I do recomendo to display 
         your Queues and check out which one is the correct in your case***.
   - Add frequent flyer number (Optional)
   - Add form of payment (Optional, you can add it later, but a good practice is to add during this session)

> Note, you can have additional steps like adding Remarks, SSR and
>   etc... I'm justing listing the basic ones.